# syntax error near unexpected token `'joint_states listener''

Tags: ros, nodes, joint-states

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In this tutorial - http://wiki.ros.org/pr2_controllers/Tutorials/Getting%20the%20current%20joint%20angles

I was trying to run the service node for getting the current joint angles but the screen shows the message stated below.-

```
~/groovy_workspace/sandbox/joint_states_listener$ rosrun joint_states_listener joint_states_listener.py
/home/roger/groovy_workspace/sandbox/joint_states_listener/nodes/joint_states_listener.py: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `'joint_states_listener''
```

I am following the tutorial stepwise and havent missed any. Dont know what the problem is. Pls help.

I am using geoovy and ubuntu 12.04

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/151766/syntax-error-near-unexpected-token-%60%27joint_states-listener%27%27/) by [Ros_newbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/14601/ros_newbie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2014-04-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This sounds like you have a syntax error on line 6 in your python program.

Without seeing the source code, I can't say anything more than that.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0